# Unrelated commits are included in a pull request on Github enterprise

Tags: git, github

Our team recently introduced Github Enterprise and I have been struggling with PRs.

I created a branch 'funk/worker_item#digests' from master then I commit test-A after checking out the branch then pushed. When I tried to create a PR, I noticed that the branch also had other unrelated commits, which were referred to by many branches as illustrated [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5zQ9.png). What could have cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was using my private Github account stored in IntelliJ IDEA and seems my commits were pushed successfully to our project in Github. That must be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

A PR is a branch. Those are not "unrelated" commits, but the ancestors of the tip. To merge a PR will include the tip and all of its ancestors. If you don't want those ancestors, you need to find the merge-base of your PR branch and the target branch by `git merge-base <PR-branch> <target-branch>`. Create a new branch from this base and apply the commit `test-A` onto it, by `git cherry-pick` or `git rebase` or other methods. And then push this new branch as the PR. This PR has only one new commit that's not yet applied in the target branch.

I'm not familiar with how PR works in Github. Maybe you can tell the repository owner to apply just the last commit of your current PR by `git cherry-pick`, instead of merging the whole PR.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I understood that test-A was the only commit for this branch 'funk/worker_item#digests' as I created the branch from master then checked it out and commit. But yes, test-A has a parent commit, which is referred to by two branches, 'funk/worker_item#digests', which I can kind of understand, and another branch 'funk_add_tag'. It would be really appreciated if you give me comments about why this happens...

Comment: @uemurm Please read https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph.